# Can only access certain BeautifulSoup result elements with negative indices

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 to parse a document and I'm getting some weird behavior, the relevant piece of code looks like this:

```
for sale_table in sales_soup.find_all('table'):
    rows = sale_table.find_all('tr')
    grantor = rows[3]
```

However this gives me an index out of range exception.  So I ran some basic checks and len(rows) == 4 immediately before and after the grantor assignment (using an index that does not throw an exception).  Also I am able to access the first and second elements of rows with rows[0] and rows[1].  However I can only access elements 3 and 4 with rows[-1] and rows[-2], trying to use indexes, 2 or 3 or -3 or -4 throw an index out of range exception.  Also when I file.write(str(rows)) and the html I get matches precisely the html of the test document.

In summation I can access the entire list, but I'd like to understand why I am getting this strange exception.

Sorry guys the answer is that I am an idiot.  There is an inconsistent table in the markup that is shorter and is throwing the exception.  Running the loop one at a time shows that len != 4 on each iteration sorry for the misinformation.  Is it bad form to edit this question out since it is incorrect?

Comment: Except, AFAIR, `find_all` doesn't return a list, it returns some BS object. So, probably, a bug in BS4.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I understand you don't like it, but isn't calling it a BS object going too far? :)

Comment: Can you provide a dump of the contents of `row` after the `find_all`?

Comment: @EduardoIvanec: Hey, I'm not going to spell BeautifulSoup over and over again. Especially that I always fail to get "beautiful" right on the first go. :P

Comment: Try `rows = list(sale_table.find_all('tr'))`. Can you exclude `rows[-1] == rows[1]`, so it actually only has two elements? The inability of accessing `rows[-2]` is consistent with that.

Comment: Do you really need to embed the trigger in a for-loop? I suggest making a list `alltables = list(sales_soup.find_all('table'))`, so you can inspect the particular element that's giving you the problem. You might be surprised.

Comment: I just saw @Anony suggested essentially the same thing... whatever, just get a hold of either the top or the embedded object as a solid variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should never index a list of unknown size. Never trust the markup to be right all the time.

In my experience with BeautifulSoup, you have to write a lot of if-statements to cover for yourself. Change the above code to something like this:

```
for sale_table in sales_soup.find_all('table'):
  rows = sale_table.find_all('tr')
  if len(rows) > 3:
    grantor = rows[3]
  else:
    grantor = None
```

Also, look at the [BS4 documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) for more options to `.find_all()` that might be helpful for your use-case. If you're only getting the 4th element, for example, use `limit=4` as a keyword argument.